# jquery click not working on owl carousel callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I used `owl carousel` plugin and `bootstrap` , what i have done so far is when you reach to last item of owl carousel it going to append a **submit button** instead of **next button** via `callback` i want when click on submit button do something but problem is `click` function not working although i used `on` handler but still not working.

```
$('#btn-submit').on('click',function(){
alert('submit clicked');
});
```

<kbd>[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/stujs2h9/)</kbd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The submit button is appended after attaching the event. So, delegate the event:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-submit', function(){
    alert('submit clicked');
});
```

[<kbd>Updated fiddle</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/stujs2h9/1/)

Comment: Thanks this works fine, and i figured out what was my problem, thanks.